# calling another function of list of str to new function list of list

Tags: python

I'm trying use my previous function `calculate_total_sentiment(tweet1):` which sorts out the tweet into different category of `"very positive", "positive", "neutral, "negative"` and `"very negative"`.

Now I want to use this new function of `group_by_sentiment` which takes in a list of strings and i want to categorize them in the same category as my `calculate_total_sentiment`.

How do i sort them out like that? Below is my code of `calculate_total_sentiment` which works and i'm trying to figure out how to implement that function to this new one and making it sort into the same category.

Examples of `group_by_sentiment` would be

```
group_by_sentiment(['sad', '#notok'])
    [[], [], [], [], ['sad', 'notok']]
```

which the last of the list would contain all the very negative category while the first is very positive

```
def calculate_total_sentiment(tweet1):
    total = negative_word_score(tweet) + positive_word_score(tweet) + \
    positive_hashtag_score(tweet) + negative_hashtag_score(tweet) + \
    emoticon_score(tweet)
    if total > 2:
        return ("Very Positive")
    elif total > 0:
        return ("Positive")
    elif total == 0:
        return ("Neutral")
    elif total > -3:
        return ("Negative")
    else:
        return ("Very Negative")


def group_by_sentiment(L):
    very_negative = []
    negative = []
    neutral = []
    positive = []
    very_positive = []
    output = [very_positive, positive, neutral, negative, very_negative]
    for char in range(len(L)):
        if calculate_total_sentiment(tweet1) == 'Very Positive':
            output[0].append(very_positive)
        elif calculate_total_sentiment(tweet1) == 'Positive':
            output[1].append(positive)
        elif calculate_total_sentiment(tweet1) == 'Neutral':
            output[2].append(neutral)
        elif calculate_total_sentiment(tweet1) == 'Negative':
            output[3].append(negative)
        elif calculate_total_sentiment(tweet1) == 'Very Negative':
            output[4].append(very_negative)
    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but is there any reason you aren't using a dictionary (or is this particular case a `defaultdict`):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def group_by_sentiment(L):
    output = defaultdict(list)
    for tweet in L:
        output[calculate_total_sentiment(tweet)].append(tweet)]
    return output
>>> group_by_sentiment(['sad', '#notok'])
defaultdict(list, {'Very Negative': ['sad', '#notok']})
```

You obviously have a number of other issues with your code like `tweet` not being defined in `calculate_total_sentiment` because the arg is called `tweet1`

Comment: It's because the calculate_total_sentiment is a function which calls upon my previous functions and they all add up to a certain number which is then summed up in calculate_total_sentiment. which i tried multiple example of that function and it works. But just this new one which categorize the list of string into a list of list doesn't work but im not sure where i went wrong and how to fix it

Comment: Also im trying to sort them out in specific order of the list in group_by_sentiment which the first list [ [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] ] is all the very positive categorized already by calculate_total_sentiment will go there and so on

Comment: Sorry, then I can't help you. I don't understand your question and you obviously have a specific implementation in mind.